# ActiveAdmin: How to have a specific set of resources while downloading them all in CSV format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, export-to-csv

AcitveAdmin provides a link at the bottom of the index page to download all resources in multiple formats, and one of the formats is CSV. It is gonna take all the resources, put them in a CSV file, and give that back to us. In my situation, I have a condition that there are certain resources that can be downloaded via CSV, like:

```
User.downloadables
```

But I'm unable to figure it out how to give this set instead of `User.all` to CSV format?

I have looked into documentation, and it doesn't say much except changing the layout of a CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, I couldn't find a way to pass a specific set of records to CSV file, so I wrote the custom controller method for it in ActiveAdmin, and that's how I accomplished it:

**app/models/user.rb**:

```
scope :downloadables, -> { where(status: :downloadable) }

def self.to_csv
  downloadable_users = User.downloadables
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << column_names
    downloadable_users.each do |user|
      csv << user.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
    end
  end
end
```

**app/admin/user.rb**:

First, I generated a collection action that will let us download CSV file:

```
collection_action :download_csv do
  redirect_to action: :download_csv
end
```

Now, to have a link on index page through which one would be able to download the records in CSV file:

```
action_item only: :index do
  link_to "Download CSV", download_csv_admin_users_path
end
```

And finally to have a controller method that will actually call the method from model, and do the rest of the magic:

```
controller do
  def download_csv
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { send_data User.to_csv, filename: "users-#{Data.today}.csv" }
    end
  end
end
```

And that's it. It is working.

Comment: Good it really works!
But how it looks a little bit weird because `xml` and `json` download links are shown in the bottom and `csv` download link in the top. How can I made it appear at the bottom of the page as the other ones? I mean in the same position as the other default ones.

Comment: @AlexVentura Obviously, you can use custom styles for this purpose.

Comment: Yes I know but how to set this link into the same container as the default ones? Because as an `action_item` it appears in the menu bar. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can also customize the csv export as well for active admin.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  csv force_quotes: true, col_sep: ';', column_names: false do
    column :title
    column(:author) { |post| post.author.full_name }
  end
end
```

Cheers

Comment: That's what I said in question. Docs says about changing the layout of CSV file, and so tells your answer. What I need is a way to put a set of particular set of resources in CSV file. Thank you by the way for your answer brother.